# HTML element is attached to a document

Tags: javascript, html, dom

When an element is removed from the DOM using `removeChild()`, the reference to the element still exist but the element is no more in the DOM.
How to know if an HTML element (or its parents) is still attached to a document ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From http://code.google.com/p/doctype-mirror/wiki/ArticleNodeContains:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
        <script>
            function contains(parent, descendant) {
                return parent == descendant || Boolean(parent.compareDocumentPosition(descendant) & 16);
            }
            window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
                var p = document.getElementById("test");
                //document.body.removeChild(p);
                alert(contains(document, p));
            }, false);
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p id="test">test</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

I only tested in Opera though.

There are alternatives on that page too.

Comment: @0x89 Found an alternate address and fixed the link. Thanks for reporting.

Comment: For anyone curious about what the 16 represents its a constant variable `Node.DOCUMENT_POSITION_CONTAINED_BY` as described at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/compareDocumentPosition . Also this method is not supported in IE 8 and lower.

Answer (score 30):

You can use [`Node#contains()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/contains) to check whether the element is inside a specific document or another element:

```
if(document.contains(yourElement)) {
    // Yep, it's attached to the current document
}
```

Or [`Node#isConnected`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/isConnected) to check whether the it's connected to *any* document:

```
if(yourElement.isConnected) {
    // Yep, it's attached to any documents
}
```

Notes for elements inside a Shadow DOM:

- `.contains()` requires `getRootNode()` calls to get to the top-most element in the main document, maybe recursively: `document.contains(yourElement.getRootNode().host)`
- `.isConnected` will be `true` even if the element isn't connected to the main `document`, for example if it's inside a Shadow DOM or an iframe that are *not* inside the current document.

Comment: `document.contains` does not work for ie11 but `document.body.contains` does.

Comment: This does not work with elements nested within a Shadow DOM.

Comment: @electrovir Good point. I added some notes for it and an alternative solution. There's no silver bullet and it depends on what you're looking for.

Answer (score 16):

For newer browsers (no IE support), you can use `Node.isConnected`, which is a property on `Node` and returns a boolean.

[Mozilla Node.isConnected](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/isConnected)

```
document.querySelectorAll('#myElement').isConnected;
```

Answer (score 11):

Keep checking the element's parentNode until you get to the document or run out of nodes.

```
function is_element_in_document ( element ) {
    if (element === document) {
        return true;
    }
    element = element.parentNode;
    if (element) {
        return is_element_in_document ( element );
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Please do not use recursion! Recursion is not necessarily evil, but is greatly harms performance! If you were 90 nodes deep in the tree, then there would be 90 `element` variables in memory (one at each level) required in order to do this recursion. Moreover, if you are more than a few hundred nodes deep, then you may have a stackoverflow. Moreoversomemore, this stackoverflow is completely browser dependent, so some browsers will load the page properly while others will error out.

Answer (score 9):

Check for its `parentNode` property if it's directly attached to the document. It's `null` if there is no such parent element and otherwise a reference to the parent element.

The next code illustrates its usage, it prints `null`, `[Object HTMLBodyElement]` and `null`.

```
var elm = document.createElement("p");
alert(elm.parentNode);

document.body.appendChild(elm);
alert(elm.parentNode);

elm.parentNode.removeChild(elm);
alert(elm.parentNode);
```

Note again that this only applies to elements which have been removed using `removeChild`, if a parent element was removed, you would have to check the `parentNode` property on that parent element.

To find out if an element is *really* part of a document, you would have to check if the uppermost parent element is `document`.

```
function element_is_part_of_document(element) {
    /* as long as the element is not document, and there is a parent element */
    while (element != document && element.parentNode) {
        /* jump to the parent element */
        element = element.parentNode;
    }
    /* at this stage, the parent is found. If null, the uppermost parent element */
    /* is not document, and therefore the element is not part of the document */
    return element == document;
}
```

Comment: This will tell you if an element is attached to another element, but not to the document.

Comment: @David: True, but in the context of the answer, it does not look like an issue. I keep improving the answer ;)

Comment: Quentin, the question says "a node or its parents", so Lekensteyn's answer is correct